# How to have an enum lookup table with created and updated date?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, enums

I am using Spring + Hibernate to take care of data access layer operations. I want to create an enum lookup table in the database with below attributes:

1. Code
2. Description
3. Created Date
4. Updated Date

I have the code to take care of enum lookup table. I do not know how to add in Create Date and Updated Date in such a way that can be used by other enum classes as well.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Enum makes more sense to me now than ever. Add in all the data fields and create a constructor.
To save a custom enum needed. It's mentioned here:

```
public enum Samples implements StringValuedEnum {
SampleA("V", "Sample A"), 
SampleB("M", "Sample B");

private String dbCode;
private String description;

Brand(String dbCode, String description){
    this.setDbCode(dbCode);
    this.setDescription(description);
}


@Override
public String getDbCode() {
    return this.dbCode;
}

public void setDbCode(String dbCode) {
    this.dbCode = dbCode;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}
}
```

/**
* Utility class designed to inspect StringValuedEnums.
*/

```
public class StringValuedEnumReflect {

/**
 * Don't let anyone instantiate this class.
 * 
 * @throws UnsupportedOperationException
 *             Always.
 */
private StringValuedEnumReflect() {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException(
            "This class must not be instanciated.");
}

/**
 * All Enum constants (instances) declared in the specified class.
 * 
 * @param enumClass
 *            Class to reflect
 * @return Array of all declared EnumConstants (instances).
 */
private static <T extends Enum<T>> T[] getValues(Class<T> enumClass) {
    return enumClass.getEnumConstants();
}

/**
 * All possible string values of the string valued enum.
 * 
 * @param enumClass
 *            Class to reflect.
 * @return Available string values.
 */
public static <T extends Enum<T> & StringValuedEnum> String[] getStringValues(
        Class<T> enumClass) {
    T[] values = getValues(enumClass);
    String[] result = new String[values.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        result[i] = values[i].getDbCode();
    }
    return result;
}

/**
 * Name of the enum instance which hold the especified string value. If
 * value has duplicate enum instances than returns the first occurency.
 * 
 * @param enumClass
 *            Class to inspect.
 * @param value
 *            String.
 * @return name of the enum instance.
 */
public static <T extends Enum<T> & StringValuedEnum> String getNameFromValue(
        Class<T> enumClass, String value) {
    T[] values = getValues(enumClass);
    for (T v : values) {
        if (v.getDbCode().equals(value)) {
            return v.name();
        }
    }
    return "";
}
```

}

Class extending EnhancedUserType:

//Please notice the calls to getNameFromValue *************************

```
 public class StringValuedEnumType<T extends Enum<T> & StringValuedEnum>
    implements EnhancedUserType, ParameterizedType {

/**
 * Enum class for this particular user type.
 */
private Class<T> enumClass;


/** Creates a new instance of ActiveStateEnumType */
public StringValuedEnumType() {
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Override
public void setParameterValues(Properties parameters) {
    String enumClassName = parameters.getProperty("enumClass");
    try {
        enumClass = (Class<T>) Class.forName(enumClassName)
                .asSubclass(Enum.class).asSubclass(StringValuedEnum.class); // Validates
                                                                            // the
                                                                            // class
                                                                            // but
                                                                            // does
                                                                            // not
                                                                            // eliminate
                                                                            // the
                                                                            // cast
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException cnfe) {
        throw new HibernateException("Enum class not found", cnfe);
    }

}

/**
 * The class returned by <tt>nullSafeGet()</tt>.
 * 
 * @return Class
 */
@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
public Class returnedClass() {
    return enumClass;
}

public int[] sqlTypes() {
    return new int[] { Types.VARCHAR };
}

public boolean isMutable() {
    return false;
}

/**
 * Retrieve an instance of the mapped class from a JDBC resultset.
 * Implementors should handle possibility of null values.
 * 
 * @param rs
 *            a JDBC result set
 * @param names
 *            the column names
 * @param owner
 *            the containing entity
 * @return Object
 * @throws HibernateException
 * @throws SQLException
 */
@Override
public Object nullSafeGet(ResultSet rs, String[] names, SessionImplementor session, Object owner)
        throws HibernateException, SQLException {
    String value = rs.getString(names[0]);
    if (value == null) { // no default value
        return null;
    }
    String name = getNameFromValue(enumClass, value);
    Object res = rs.wasNull() ? null : Enum.valueOf(enumClass, name);

    return res;
}

/**
 * Write an instance of the mapped class to a prepared statement.
 * Implementors should handle possibility of null values. A multi-column
 * type should be written to parameters starting from <tt>index</tt>.
 * 
 * @param st
 *            a JDBC prepared statement
 * @param value
 *            the object to write
 * @param index
 *            statement parameter index
 * @param session
 *            session   
 * @throws HibernateException
 * @throws SQLException
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Override
public void nullSafeSet(PreparedStatement st, Object value, int index, SessionImplementor session)
        throws HibernateException, SQLException {
    if (value == null) {
        st.setNull(index, Types.CHAR);
    } else {
        st.setString(index, ((T) value).getDbCode());
    }      
}

public Object assemble(Serializable cached, Object owner)
        throws HibernateException {
    return cached;
}

public Serializable disassemble(Object value) throws HibernateException {
    return (Enum<?>) value;
}

public Object deepCopy(Object value) throws HibernateException {
    return value;
}

public boolean equals(Object x, Object y) throws HibernateException {
    return x == y;
}

public int hashCode(Object x) throws HibernateException {
    return x.hashCode();
}

public Object replace(Object original, Object target, Object owner)
        throws HibernateException {
    return original;
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public String objectToSQLString(Object value) {
    return '\'' + ((T) value).getDbCode() + '\'';
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public String toXMLString(Object value) {
    return ((T) value).getDbCode();
}

public Object fromXMLString(String xmlValue) {
    String name = getNameFromValue(enumClass, xmlValue);
    return Enum.valueOf(enumClass, name);
}
}
```

Sample Entity class

```
 @Entity
```

@Table(name = "TCSM_BUS_ENTY")
@DynamicUpdate
public class SampleClient extends java.io.Serializable {

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
@Column(name = "SID")
private Long id;

@Column(name = "SAMPLE_NM")
@Type(type = "com.sample.data.common.StringValuedEnumType", parameters = { @Parameter(name = "enumClass", value = "com.sample.data.model.types.BusinessType") })
private Sample sample;
 }
```